# VueJs - promise returned but redirection does not happen

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, vue.js

I am building a login with Vue, Node, Express and Mongodb. I can successfully save a user to a database upon registration but I want to redirect the user to a different component after he is registered.

Problem: after my user gets saved nothing happens and I am left on the same Registration component. I'm not sure if I am suppose to redirect my response from the server or the client..

I see the console log `registering` but I cannot see the console log `registration successful` and I am not sure why.. could anyone help please?

**-------CLIENT CODE-------**

Registration.vue

```
<template>
  <v-layout >
    <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
      <div class="white elevation-2">
        <v-toolbar flat dense class="blue" dark>
          <v-toolbar-title>Register</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>

        <div class="pl-4 pr-4 pt-2 pb-2">
          <v-text-field label="email" v-model="email"/>
          <br>
          <v-text-field label="password" v-model="password"/>
          <br>
          <div class="error" v-html="error"></div>
          <v-btn class="blue" dark @click="register">Register</v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import AuthenticationService from '../services/AuthenticationService'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async register (res, req) {
        try {
          console.log('registering');
          const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          });
          res.status(200).send('registration successful'); // I NEVER SEE THIS!!
          console.log('registration successful: ' + response.data);
          this.$router.push('dashboard')
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error during reg on front eng');
          this.error = error.response.data.error;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

authenticationService.js

```
import Api from '../services/Api'

export default {
  register(credentials) {
    return Api().post('register', credentials);
  },
  login(credentials) {
    return Api().post('login', credentials);
  }
}
```

Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'
  })
}
```

**-------SERVER CODE-------**

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const cors = require('cors');

require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');


// grab db access for admin rights
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

//create an app using express route handlers
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// allow the app to use cookies
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

// tell passport to use cookies
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// this file returns a function which uses app object as an arg
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

authRoutes.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const authenticationController = require('../controllers/AuthenticationController');
const authenticationControllerPolicy = require('../policies/AuthenticationControllerPolicy');

/**
 * Authentication routing for Google OAuth
 * @type {Passport}
 */
module.exports = (app) => {

    app.post('/register',
        //authenticationControllerPolicy.register,
        authenticationController.register);


};
```

authenticationController.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/config');
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = {

    async register(req, res) {
        console.log('authenticationController: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

        try {
            const user = await User.find({email: req.body.email}).count();

            if(user) {
                console.log('user exists in db');
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('creating new user entry');
                const newUser = await new User({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password
                }).save();
                res.send(newUser);
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `AuthenticationService.register` is actually returning a promise correctly?

> The await expression causes `async` function execution to pause until  a `Promise` is fulfilled, that is resolved or rejected, and to resume execution of the `async` function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the `await` expression is that of the fulfilled `Promise`.

For more info see [MDN web docs - await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: you know that's a good question, one which I don't have an answer to. I just added at `res.send(res.user);` in my `authenticationController` because I believe I need to return a response form the server to the client. Unfortunately, this caused further issues on my front-end where I receive an error like this `Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined ` 
    `at VueComponent._callee$ (Register.vue?b5de:33)`

Comment: Thats probably caused by forgetting to `return` the inner promise, see [Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection. Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927765/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: inside the `authenticationController`'s `else` statement? `return res.send(newUser);` ??

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly understand why I have to return anything and where? the original promise is made in the `Register` component and further promises are made on the backend as well.. when I try to return in any of those places I still get the `TypeError` above.. can you please clarify what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

once I commented out this line in `Registration.vue` everything worked.

`res.status(200).send('registration successful');`

not sure why..