# How to fetch response message from Laravel API?

Tags: laravel, post

I am using Laravel at backend and Aurelia on front. I know this has been answered many times before but none solution is working out for me. I want to send custom messages back in aurelia and extract them.
Thing I am trying to do:

```
//post api
.then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => {                   
        
           if(jsonData.msg== true)  
           {                
            document.getElementById('close_add_new_modal').click();
           } else {
            console.log(`Error!`); 
           }
        
      });
```

Every time here I get the exception:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Backend: How I am trying to send msg:

```
 return response()->json(['msg' => 'true']);
```

To solve the error I referred to this post:
[Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection. Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927765/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Followed, but issue remained same.
Could anyone tell me where am I wrong or what is correct way of fetching custom messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
return json_encode(['msg' => 'true']);
```

and also try to use aurelia-fetch-client for api requests handling

```
import `{HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
```

https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/http-services/

Comment: Though I declared this answer right but I have one more question. This method works fine while dealing with update method... but when you use "post" and then wanted to receive response same errors comes as mentioned above. 
````Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined````